# Testing expressions with === (SameQ) between original expression and after Factor[], Expand[] and FullSimplify[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

```
a=16x^4 y^5 (81-z^4)-54xy^2 (81-z^4)
```

> Out[30]= -54 xy^2 (81-z^4)+16 x^4 y^5 (81-z^4)

```
b=Factor[a]
```

> Out[31]= 2 (27 xy^2-8 x^4 y^5) (-3+z) (3+z) (9+z^2)

```
c=Expand[a]
```

> Out[45]= -4374 xy^2+1296 x^4 y^5+54 xy^2 z^4-16 x^4 y^5 z^4

```
d= FullSimplify[a]
```

> Out[33]= 2 (27 xy^2-8 x^4 y^5) (-81+z^4)

```
a==b
```

> Out[47]= -54 xy^2 (81-z^4)+16 x^4 y^5 (81-z^4)==2 (27 xy^2-8 x^4 y^5) (-3+z) (3+z) (9+z^2)

```
a===b
```

> Out[46]= False

```
a==c
```

> Out[43]= -54 xy^2 (81-z^4)+16 x^4 y^5 (81-z^4)==-4374 xy^2+1296 x^4 y^5+54 xy^2 z^4-16 x^4 y^5 z^4

```
a===c
```

> Out[40]= False

```
a==d
```

> Out[44]= -54 xy^2 (81-z^4)+16 x^4 y^5 (81-z^4)==2 (27 xy^2-8 x^4 y^5) (-81+z^4)

```
a===d
```

> Out[41]= False

**Questions:** As I understand `==` should not work, because it is only for numeric expressions and my is symbolic. Buy what about `===`? Why `===` is not giving me `True` in all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` is for mathematical equivalence, but it may not evaluate. You may need Simplify, Refine or similar to make it evaluate.

`===` is for structural equivalence, and it always evaluates. It is `True` if and only if the two expressions are structurally identical (i.e. their FullForm is exactly the same). You basically never want `===` with symbolic math.

Comment: So how exactly should I check from my code if `a` equals to `b`, `c`, `d`?

Comment: What is the code to get the `True` results in that cases?

Comment: @vasili111 As I said, use `==` with (Full)Simplify. [There is no algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) to check if two expressions are equal for any value of the variable, so there will not be a way that always returns True or False and will never tell you "I don't know".

Comment: Those worked: `FullSimplify[a] == FullSimplify[b]`, `FullSimplify[a] == FullSimplify[c]`, `FullSimplify[a] == FullSimplify[d]`. Also `===` worked that way too. Thank you.

Comment: In which cases `==` and `===` may be different with (Full)Simplify?

Comment: No, use `FullSimplify[a==b]`. As I already said, *do not* use `===` for math, ever.